# Features of vector form of sentences for opinion finding.

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, word2vec

I want to find the opinion of a sentence either positive or negative. For example talk about only one sentence.

`The play was awesome`

If change it to vector form

`[0,0,0,0]`

After searching through the Bag of words

```
bad
naughty
awesome
```

The vector form becomes

`[0,0,0,1]`

Same for other sentences. Now I want to pass it to the machine learning algorithm for training it. **How can I train the network using these multiple vectors?** (for finding the opinion of unseen sentences) Obviously not! Because the input is fix in neural network. Is there any way? The above procedure is just my thinking. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your intuitive input format is "Sentence". Which is, indeed, a string of tokens with **arbitrary** length. Abstracting sentences as token series is not a good choice for many existing algorithms only works on determined format of inputs.

Hence, I suggest try using **tokenizer** on your entire training set. This will give you vectors of length of the dictionary, which is fixed for given training set.

Because when the length of sentences vary drastically, then size of the dictionary always keeps stable.

Then you can apply Neural Networks(or other algorithms) to the tokenized vectors.

**However**, vectors generated by tokenizer is **extremely sparse** because you only work on sentences rather than articles.

You can try [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) (supervised, not [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)), to reduce the dimension as well as amplify the difference.

That will keep the essential information of your training data as well as express your data at fixed size, while this "size" is not too large.

By the way, you may not have to label each word by its attitude since the opinion of a sentence also depends on other kind of words.

Simple arithmetics on number of opinion-expressing words many leave your model highly biased. Better label the sentences and leave the rest job to classifiers.

> For the confusions
>
> PCA and LDA are Dimensional Reduction techniques.
>   [difference](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-LDA-and-PCA-for-dimension-reduction)
>
> Let's assume each tuple of sample is denoted as `x` (1-by-p vector).
>
> p is too large, we don't like that.
>
> Let's find a matrix A(p-by-k) in which k is pretty small.
>
> So we get `reduced_x` = `x*A`, and most importantly, `reduced_x` must
>   be able to represent `x`'s characters.
>
> Given labeled data, LDA can provide proper A that can maximize
>   distance between `reduced_x` of different classes, and also minimize
>   the distance within identical classes.
>
> In simple words: compress data, keep information.
>
> When you've got
>   `reduced_x`, you can define training data: `(reduced_x|y)` where y is
>   0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks for your highly appreciable reply. I did not understand **1.** `NN` in your sentence in `Then you can apply NN to the tokenized vectors.` What is `NN`? **2.** What will be the `LDA` do? **3.** If I label the sentences for training. How it will be beneficial? For example: I have dictionary of 10 words and the sentence `I love my cat (Pos)` turns to `[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]` (Love=1) what should I do with **(Pos)** that is tag of sentence?

Comment: Please have a look at the supplements. Also, when you dict size is 10, the sentence maybe looks like that `[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]` since your sentence contains 4 words.

Comment: If you are not very familiar with machine learning, I suggest you read some books or maybe try some Coursera courses to systematically understand data-preprocessing\labelling\modelling..., which should relieve you of many fundamental confusions. Hope this will be helpful.